# Inability to export the correct data to .csv using select-object in Powershell

Tags: powershell

So, this is probably a rookie error.  As y'all can see, I am trying to print out the `NetworkPath` and `Permissions` for the directories that have "Permissions Denied". I know the problem has to do with how I am piping from

```
$AccessPresentation |
    Select-Object -Property NetworkPath, Permissions |
        export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $AccessDeniedFolders
```

Specifically, it appears to me that I am having with `Select-Object`, but I don't know what I have done wrong.  When you run the code, and then open the .csv, all it does is provide `NetworkPath` and `Permissions`, and for the values `System.Objects[]`.  What have I done wrong?

```
$AccessDeniedFolders = "c:\users\john.smith\desktop\AccessDeniedFolders.csv"

$AccessPresentation = @()

$AccessDeniedError = @()

$Properties = @{}

$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\ -recurse -ea silentlycontinue -ErrorVariable +AccessDeniedError | ?{$_.PSIsContainer} | Out-Null

$AccessDeniedError | select -expand categoryinfo

$Properties = @{'NetworkPath'=$AccessDeniedError.TargetObject;'Permissions'=$AccessDeniedError.CategoryInfo.Category}

$AccessPresentation += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties

$AccessPresentation | Select-Object -Property NetworkPath, Permissions | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $AccessDeniedFolders
```

Comment: the CSV format does NOT support complex objects. [*grin*] this `System.Objects[]` indicates you are trying to put an array into a _single property_. that won't work. ///// depending on just what is in that array, you may be able to use the `-join` operator to make it into a string of the values.

Comment: this line `$Properties = @{` is putting EVERYTHING into one object. [*grin*] you need to rewrite your logic to iterate thru the collection and put the items in one at a time instead of all-at-once.

Comment: Yep.  Rookie mistake.  I really appreciate the help!

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]